# Ansible podman deploy

Tags: ansible, podman, podman-compose

I'm trying to create a playbook which configures a RHEL 8 machine with a container. It all seems to go just fine until i try to use environment variables. That gives me the following error:

FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "argument env is of type <class 'list'> and we were unable to convert to dict: <class 'list'> cannot be converted to a dict"}
2021-03-06T12:09:19.0217935Z

My code is as follows:

```
  - name: Run zookeeper container
    containers.podman.podman_container:
    name: zookeeper
    image: bitnami/zookeeper:3.6.2
    state: started
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
      - 3181:3181
      - 10001:10001
      - 2888:2888
      - 3888:3888
    env:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN= "yes"
```

I've tried a lot of different combinations but i cannot seem to get it too work.

Any idea's?

Ansible version is 2.9.0.

Rick.

Answer (score 2):

The error is accurate: the `env` keyword expects a dictionary, but you're providing a list. Just make it a dictionary and it will work fine:

```
- name: Run zookeeper container
  containers.podman.podman_container:
    name: zookeeper
    image: bitnami/zookeeper:3.6.2
    state: started
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
      - 3181:3181
      - 10001:10001
      - 2888:2888
      - 3888:3888
    env:
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: "yes"
```

The documentation shows this clearly in [the example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/containers/podman/podman_container_module.html#examples).